# How to do conditionals in xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I have this XML file:

```
$ cat conditional.xml
<a>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
</a>

$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m '/a/*' -v 'concat("hello ",name())' -n conditional.xml
hello b
hello c
```

I want to do some conditional things. I want to say "hello" to element **'a'** and I want to say "howdy" to element **'b'**. This based on the name of the element which is known in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `--if --else --break` (or `-i --else -b`) construct (see [the docs](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139652416)) :

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m '/a/*' \
    --if 'name()="b"' -o "hello " --else -o 'howdy ' --break \
    -v 'name()' -n conditional.xml
hello b
howdy c
```